# purpose of __get__ of a simple function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to ask what is the purpose of simple function `__get__` and why if behaves differently than descriptor class `__get__`?

My investigation:

```
import inspect

def a(x, y):
    return x + y

def wr(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print f.__name__, 'called with', args, kwargs
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

print inspect.getsource(a)
# def a(x, y):
#     return x + y

print inspect.getsource(a.__get__) # we cannot inspect it because it is a method-wrapper
# Traceback (most recent call last):
# ...
#     'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
# TypeError: <method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x7fd43591e140> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object

a.__get__ = wr(a.__get__) # replace with function that delegates work and prints passed arguments
a2 = a.__get__(2) # we can use __get__ for functools.partial purposes
# __get__ called with (2,) {}

print a.__class__, a2.__class__ # it looks like a is a normal function and a2 is a bound function, but there is no instance
# <type 'function'> <type 'instancemethod'>

print 'a2 result:', a2(3)
# a2 result: 5

print inspect.getsource(a2) # source the same as function a
# def a(x, y):
#     return x + y
```

We know descriptor class `__get__` method signature [object.__get__(self, instance, owner)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) and it looks like that it does not match functions `a.__get__` signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python functions are descriptors.  This is how method objects are created.  When you do `obj.method`, the descriptor protocol  is activated, and the function's `__get__` method is called.  This returns a bound method.

That's why you see `a2` as an instancemethod.  When you do `a.__get__(2)`, you are passing `2` as the "instance" argument to `__get__`.  If you do `print(a2)`, you will see `<bound method ?.a of 2>`, indicating Python thinks `a2` is a bound method of the object `2`.

The `owner` argument is optional in the descriptor protocol (or at least in functions' implementation of it), which is why you are able to call `__get__` with only one argument.  You *can* call `a.__get__(2, 1)` and get a similar object back.

Comment: When we call `__get__(self, instance, owner) ` on function as arguments are passed: `self` is a function itself, instance is `2` and owner is `None` since it is optional. 
Functions `__get__` method expects that function itself expects instance (`self`) as first argument, therefore it returns bound method which allways gets passed instance as first argument. Since we pass `2` in place of instance we get `2` passed as first argument in our `a2` function. Am I correct?

Comment: @user1915011: I'm not sure I understand you.  `a.__get__` doesn't actually care what arguments `a` accepts.  The `self` that is passed to `a.__get__` is, as you say, the function `a` itself.  `a.__get__` does not "check" to see what arguments `a` accepts.  If `a` is a function, `a.__get__` *always* returns a bound method object unless you pass `None` as the "instance" argument (in which case it returns an unbound method).

Comment: Looks like an alternative (more elegant but less comprehensible) implementation of closure? Here the object a becomes an implicit parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This `__get__` is a standard descriptor `__get__`. The data model doesn't reflect this, but the `owner` argument to `__get__` is frequently made optional, since it provides no extra information for a non-`None` `instance`. This does not violate the descriptor protocol.

A function's `__get__` is usually called the normal way descriptor `__get__` methods get called, as part of attribute access:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        return 3

foo = Foo()

# The following attribute access calls bar.__get__(foo, Foo) to create a method object.
bar_method = foo.bar
```